# Searching between dates in ddMMYYYY format in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres db that holds dates in ddMMYYYY (varchar) format. This cannot be changed because this format is already used for third party programs AND used a lot within my program.

I'm trying but i cannot think of a way to do this.

As an example:

DATES

20102019

21102019

22102019

23102019

select * from table where date is between('21102019', '22102019')?

Comment: "*This cannot be changed*" - can't you just change the few queries in the programs that expect the data in that format? Alternatively change the table and just provide a view with the old format.

Comment: As much as i'd like it, no. The date format that i call in the program i can change a little, but the table format trully cant be changed - unless i changed the queries, procedures and functions of the the third parties, which is not garanteed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert it to a date using the TO_DATE function or just reverse it to YYMMDD using string manipulation and then cast it as an integer. Either of these could be slow if its a big table.

Comment: it worked as i wished!

Here's the result, for whomever see:

SELECT
   *
FROM
   table
WHERE
    to_date(varcharColumn, 'DDMMYYYY') >= to_date('17092019', 'DDMMYYYY')
AND to_date(varcharColumn, 'DDMMYYYY') <  to_date('25112019', 'DDMMYYYY');